# Inserting data into MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing a e-commerce admin panel and I need a quick script for inserting data into MySQL. Here's what i've done and it does nothing.

```
                        <form action="#" id="form_sample_1" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
                            <div class="control-group">
                              <label class="control-label">Package Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                              <div class="controls">
                                 <input type="text" name="pkg_name" data-required="1" class="span6 " value=""/>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="control-group">
                              <label class="control-label">Package Price <span class="required">*</span><small>(In Dollars)</small></label>
                              <div class="controls">
                                 <input name="pkg_price" type="number" class="span6 " value=""/>
                              </div>
                           </div>

                           <div class="control-group">
                              <label class="control-label">Package Contains</label>
                              <div class="controls">
                                 <input name="pkg_contains" type="text" class="span6 " value=""/>
                              </div>
                           </div>

                          <div class="control-group">
                              <label class="control-label">Your Password</label>
                              <div class="controls">
                                 <input name="sifre" type="password" class="span6 " value=""/>
                             </div>
                           </div>

                           <div class="form-actions">
                           <a href="#"><button type="button"name="btn" class="btn btn-primary">Send request to server.</button></a>
                           </div>
                        </form>
                        <!-- END FORM-->

                     </div> <!--widget box light-grey end-->
 <!-- Mass PHP starts here! -->
 <?php
 echo mysql_error();
 include("include/baglan.php");
// set posts here.
$_POST['pkg_name'] = $pkg_name;
$_POST['pkg_price'] = $pkg_price;
$_POST['pkg_contains'] = $pkg_contains;

     $sifre = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['sifre']));

if($_POST['btn'] and $_POST["sifre"] = $sifre){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO packages (pkg_name, pkg_price,pkg_contains) VALUES $pkg_name $pkg_price $pkg_contains");
echo "Success.";
}
else {
echo mysql_error();}
```

It returns nothing! I've re-written all code but nothing! please help me. The databae variables are; 
id, auto incerment
pkg_name text
pkg_price int
pkg_contains mediumtext

Answer (score 0):

Assign variable name should be the left side.

```
// set posts here.
$pkg_name=$_POST['pkg_name'];
$pkg_price=$_POST['pkg_price'];
$pkg_contains=$_POST['pkg_contains'];
```

`Values()` is function, put all vars in bracket and split them with ','.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO packages (pkg_name, pkg_price,pkg_contains) VALUES($pkg_name,$pkg_price,$pkg_contains)");
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer. It still does nothing, can  you check my entire code and tell me errors so I can fix? Thanks.

Comment: It turns out nothing.

Comment: If you posting the same file you work on it, just remove action attribute from form element.

Comment: It doesn't change anything.

Comment: Still looking for answers!

Comment: Before getting post in php tag just `print_r($_POST)` and show me the output.